# How to continuously copy files into docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a docker newbie and i can't rly figure out how the changes that will be made to my working directory will be continuously copied to the docker container. Is there a command that copies all my changes to the docker container all the time ?

Edit : i added docker file and docker compose

My docker file

```
FROM scratch
ADD centos-7-x86_64-docker.tar.xz /

LABEL \
    org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0" \
    org.label-schema.name="CentOS Base Image" \
    org.label-schema.vendor="CentOS" \
    org.label-schema.license="GPLv2" \
    org.label-schema.build-date="20201113" \
    org.opencontainers.image.title="CentOS Base Image" \
    org.opencontainers.image.vendor="CentOS" \
    org.opencontainers.image.licenses="GPL-2.0-only" \
    org.opencontainers.image.created="2020-11-13 00:00:00+00:00"



RUN yum clean all && yum update -y && yum -y upgrade

RUN yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y 
RUN yum install -y wget gettext-devel curl-devel openssl-devel perl-devel perl-CPAN zlib-devel && wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.26.2.tar.gz\
&& tar -xvzf v2.26.2.tar.gz && cd git-2.26.2 && make configure && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make install




# RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
#     chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
#     ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
# RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /id_rsa 
# RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
#     echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
#     chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
#     chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN ls
RUN cd / && git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git \
&& cd odoo \
&& git fetch \
&& git checkout 9.0 

RUN yum install python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-dev openldap-devel libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel libzip-devel freetype-devel lcms2-devel \
 libwebp-devel tcl-devel tk-devel python-pip nodejs

RUN pip install setuptools==1.4.1 beautifulsoup4==4.9.3 pillow openpyxl==2.6.4 luhn gmp-devel paramiko==1.7.7.2 python2-secrets cffi pysftp==0.2.8
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN npm install -g less
CMD ["/bin/bash","git"]
```

My docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'


services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
      container_name: app
    tty: true
  db:
    image: postgres:9.2.18
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  odoo:
    <<: *app
    command: python odoo.py -w odoo -r odoo
    ports:
      - '8069:8069'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to mount a path from the host into a container which can be done using volumes. Something like this would keep the folders in sync which can be useful for development

```
docker run -v /path/to/local/folder:/path/in/container busybox
```

Comment: what is busybox ?

Comment: Used it as an example, it's a docker image containing busybox linux (https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox). It can be replaced with your own image

Comment: Sry to bother u again i added my docker compose and docker file can u tell me what to put as a docker image instead of busybox

Comment: If you're using docker compose and have your own dockerfile then you can add `build: .` to the service in docker-compose.yml to build your own dockerfile in the same directory.

For volumes you add a section like this
volumes:
  - /local/path:/container/path

This article guides you through it all https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/